# PayPal in-context checkout doesn't always trigger startFlow?

Tags: javascript, paypal

We've built an online store that integrates the PayPal in-context / express checkout. This is using the Classic NVP API.

It has been receiving the token every time and logging to the console that it is starting the payment flow. However, every now and then it will not redirect the modal to the checkout, but I can run `paypal.checkout.startFlow('<token_from_console>');` in the console and it successfully redirects.

Here's the js for the checkout process:

```
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {

    paypal.checkout.setup('<?=$paypal_merchantID?>', {
        locale: 'en_AU',
        <? if ($paypal_platform == 'sandbox') { ?>environment: 'sandbox',<? } ?>
        button: ['submitButton'],
        condition: function() {
            return $('#orderForm').valid();
        },
        click: function() {

            // INITIALISE CHECKOUT
            paypal.checkout.initXO();

            // SET EXPRESS CHECKOUT AND GET TOKEN
            setCheckout = $.post("/checkout.php?mode=setExpressCheckout", $("#orderForm").serialize());

            setCheckout.done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if (response.substr(0,2) == 'EC') {
                    paypal.checkout.startFlow(response);
                    console.log('starting paypal flow');
                }
            });

            setCheckout.fail(function(reponse){
                paypal.checkout.closeFlow();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: did you found a solution?